# What are the 32 auspicious traits of Narayana or Lord Vishnu?

Tags: scripture, puranas, vishnu, gunas

**Shree Narayana** is the Vedic Supreme God according to Vedas, Itihasas, Bhagavata Purana and Other Puranas (including his different avatars ) in Hinduism. He is also known as **Vishnu** and **Hari** and is venerated as **Purushottama**. [See More](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana)

While reading more about him , I came to know that Shree Narayana or Lord Vishnu is having **32 auspicious traits ( lakshan लक्षण) ie. similarly like  Physical characteristics.**

**Question -:** What are these 32 auspicious traits. In which scripture these are described?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Lord Narayanas of Lord Vishnu's 32 auspicious traits are mentioned in
Brahma Moksha Kanda - (Chapter 22  , Verse 4 to 17) of [**Garuda Purana**](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/garud-puran/garuda-vol-1/chapter-02/topic-21).

> तस्मादाहुर्लक्षणेत्येव् सर्वे तलक्क्षणं श्रुणु चादौ खगेन्द्र:। **नारायणे**
> पूर्ण गुणे रमेशे **द्वात्रिंश संख्याणी सुलक्षणानि** ।। 4।।
>
> Narayana,the lord of laxami is possessed of **Thirty Two** **auspicious**
> **traits**.O lord of birds,I tell them serially.The person who hears the
> same obtain quick deliverance.

These 32 auspicios traits are given below -:

> 1. The lord has seven feet 2) **Ninetysix fingers ( the author here actually is talking about about height of Lord Vishnu ,  his body is 96 fingers tall )** 3) Four Hands 4) Sharp
>    teeth  5) A loving round and blooming face 6) Un-elivated chin 7)
>    Sharp and small teeth 8) Red lips  9) Bright nails 10) Red cheeks 11)
>    Blood Red Hands 12) Marks of conch and disc  13) Thin but developed
>    belly 14) Marked with three wrinkles 15) The deep naval 16) The plump
>    pair of thighs  17) Long extensive waist 18) Well set scrotum 19)
>    Straight and elevated lower parts 20) Red soles  21) Depressed ankles
> 2. Lovely neck 23) Lotus eyes 24) Red arms and knees  25) Wide Breast
> 3. Lion like shoulders 27) Small mouth 28) Extended eyes  29) Small
>    and tender lower part 30) Even feet ,even waist ,even knee ,even
>    thighs 31) Even legs even hands 32) Even ears.

This is  the translation of shlokas (5 To 17).

In these shlokas various physical marks , or traits (Laxana) are described.

**Note - The interpretation of word 96 is provided by Tezz and Keshav Shrinivasan.. So Thank to Both .**

Comment: The seven feet and 96 fingers thing is rather strange.  As far as I know Vishnu has two feet and twenty fingers, i.e. five per each hand.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Yes , you are correct.We all know  "Vishnu" as you have said above.There might be some reason behind that description . I will also try to find related  material to that in GP. and will try to find possible explanation.

Comment: Thanks to KeshavSrinivasan and Tezz for good interpretation of sanskrit verse.

Answer (score 2):

As per "Vishnu Puran" and "Padma Puran", Lord Vishnu is said to possess not just 32 but infinite attributes, among which there are six principal attributes and other secondary attributes are infinite in number.

The principal attributes are as following:

(1) Knowledge;
(2) Power;
(3) Strength;
(4) Lordship;
(5) Energy;
(6) Splendour;

Some of the Secondary attributes are as following:
(1) Beautiful features of the entire body; 
(2) Marked with all auspicious characteristics;
 
(3) Extremely pleasing; 
(4) Effulgent; 
(5) Strong; 
(6) Ever youthful; 
(7) Wonderful linguist;
 
(8) Truthful; 
(9) Talks pleasingly; 
(10) Fluent; 
(11) Highly learned;
 
(12) Highly intelligent;
 
(13) A genius; 
(14) Artistic; 
(15) Extremely clever;
 
(16) Expert; 
(17) Grateful; 
(18) Firmly determined;
 
(19) An expert judge of time and circumstances; 
(20) Sees and speaks on the authority of Vedas, or scriptures; 
(21) Pure; 
(22) Self-controlled;
 
(23) Steadfast; 
(24) Forbearing; 
(25) Forgiving; 
(26) Grave; 
(27) Self-satisfied; 
(28) Possessing equilibrium;
 
(29) Magnanimous; 
(30) Religious; 
(31) Heroic; 
(32) Compassionate;
 
(33) Respectful; 
(34) Gentle; 
(35) Liberal; 
(36) Shy; 
(37) The protector of surrendered souls; 
(38) Happy; 
(39) The well-wisher of devotees; 
(40) Controlled by love; 
(41) All-auspicious; 
(42) Most powerful; 
(43) All-famous; 
(44) Popular; 
(45) Partial to devotees;
 
(46) Very attractive to all women; 
(47) All-worshipable; 
(48) All-opulent; 
(49) All-honorable; 
(50) The supreme controller;
(51) Inconceivable potency;
(52) Uncountable universes generate from His body;
(53) Original source of all incarnations;
(54) Giver of salvation to the enemies whom He kills;
(55) Attractor of liberated souls;

Comment: Thank you for your answer , its a nice one.But what i am expecting more is description of "Marks  with auspicious characteristics" like physical characteristics , as you said in   secondary attributes 2).

Comment: Okay. I will add if come across some genuine source. Thanks you for the motivation.